# SELENIUM PYTHON ElementClickInterceptedException:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, mern

I'm writing a Selenium Python script. Unfortunately, I can't click "Sign in" button or check mark.
I've tried many ways. I'll be glad if anyone helps me plz.
Link:
https://stagingskateontario.memberlounge.ca/auth/login

My Code:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, ":r2:")))
driver.find_element(By.ID,":r2:").click()
```

Error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (790, 723)
> (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbtgk.png)

Comment: Are you running in headless or regular mode?

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click the button with  javascript
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/main/div/div/div[2]/form/button")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Comment: Thanks, it works for me now!! Can you plz provide me more of this type of tutorial doc. I think I need to learn more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: JavaScriptExecutor is an Interface that helps to execute JavaScript through Selenium Webdriver. JavaScriptExecutor provides two methods “executescript” & “executeAsyncScript” to run javascript on the selected window or current page.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptExecutor is an Interface that helps to execute JavaScript through Selenium Webdriver. JavaScriptExecutor provides two methods “executescript” & “executeAsyncScript” to run javascript on the selected window or current page.